# Set open and closing time for each day of the week

Tags: php, xml

I have following code to check opening and closing hours and it is working fine.

```
// Set open and closing time for each day of the week
if ($weekday == "Monday") {
$open_from = "17:00";
$open_to = "21:45";
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get hours from xml file but it is not working

```
// Set open and closing time for each day of the week
if ($weekday == "Monday") {
$open_from = "<?php echo $mondayopen->nodeValue  ?>";
$open_to = "<?php echo $mondayclosed->nodeValue  ?>";
}
```

I use this code in another argument and it works fine.

```
<tr><td class="text-left">Monday</td>
<td class="text-right"><?php echo $mondayopen->nodeValue  ?> - <?php echo $mondayclosed->nodeValue  ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are using the `<?php ?>` delimiters inside a PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You can acces `$modayopen` and `$mondayclose` directly, no echoing needed:

```
// Set open and closing time for each day of the week
if ($weekday == "Monday") {
  $open_from = $mondayopen->nodeValue;
  $open_to = $mondayclosed->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your php code should be like this

```
 if ($weekday == "Monday") {
    $open_from = $mondayopen->nodeValue;
    $open_to = $mondayclosed->nodeValue;
    }
//(or)
    if ($weekday == "Monday") {
    $open_from = '"'.$mondayopen->nodeValue.'"';
    $open_to = '"'.$mondayclosed->nodeValue.'"';
    }
```